# Best practice to concatenate non-specific SPARQL queries?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I'm writing some python code to dynamically build some SPARQL query of arbitrary length.

I have a subquery that looks like this:

```
                ?topObj a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
                         rdfs:comment '{}';
                         up:range ?range.

                 ?proteins a up:Protein .
                 ?proteins up:annotation ?otherTop .
                 ?otherTop a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
                           rdfs:comment '{}';
                           up:range ?otherRange.""",
```

Where I go in and .format() the {} depending on user specified input. I want a way to stack up multiple of these subqueries that could potentially match to other objects, ie. the `rdfs:comment '{}';` line. But of course the variable names that I use to traverse to my desired object are bound in the first subquery.

Would the best solution be:

- Generate random variables to store traversed nodes for each mini-query
- Use some sort of property path/ blank node trick that I don't know about?

EDIT:

Here's an example query generated from the above template concatenated together using the random variable approach.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?proteins
WHERE {
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04439> up:annotation ?1WGQM.
    ?1WGQM a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
         rdfs:comment ?topology;
         up:range ?VLIT1 .
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01911> up:annotation ?FIICT.
    ?FIICT a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
         rdfs:comment ?topology;
         up:range ?W89B2 .
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P10321> up:annotation ?WU6G3.
    ?WU6G3 a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
         rdfs:comment ?topology;
         up:range ?ZSIQ3 .
    ?proteins a up:Protein .
    ?proteins up:annotation ?otherTop .
    ?otherTop a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
             rdfs:comment ?topology;
             up:range ?OTHERRANGE .
}
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: just to clarify, you have some constants that you use to replace the `{}` in the template then you like to issue a query that have multiple sub-selects, each of which provide solutions with different set of constants. How do you intend to join the results of these sub-selects (on which common varables)? Give us an examle query that selects the correct data so that we can gasp on what you are at after... have in mind that only variables in the projection of a sub-queriy are `visible` to the rest of the SPARQL query

Comment: I edited the post to include an example. Is there an easier way to do this? I just generated random strings to match these common nodes for an arbitrary number of these subqueries.

Comment: you could substitute the variables that have random names with blank nodes `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use BNodes instead of generating unique names for these variables, e.g. something along these lines:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?proteins
WHERE {
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04439> up:annotation [
        a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
        rdfs:comment ?topology;
        up:range [] 
    ].
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01911> up:annotation [
        a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
        rdfs:comment ?topology;
        up:range []
    ] .
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P10321> up:annotation [
        a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
        rdfs:comment ?topology;
        up:range [] 
    ].

    ?proteins a up:Protein .
    ?proteins up:annotation [
            a up:Topological_Domain_Annotation;
            rdfs:comment ?topology;
            up:range [] 
        ].
}
LIMIT 10
```

HTH